# Deleting blocked caused by thumb.db on Windows 2008 as a file server

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-7, filesystems, file-server

I have a Windows Server 2008 which I am using to store media files. I am accessing this server via a mapped drive from my Win 7. Both are x64.

When trying to delete folders, rename, move I get the following message. If I wait a while and retry, eventually the command passes. So after a while of managing my library, I have a number of these dialogs waiting for retrys. A retry interval could be a minute.
[image]

What is the best way to avoid this dialog? Could it be that i am missing some sort of "file server service" on win2008?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Would you consider completely disabling thumbnail generation a valid option?  That would certainly work.  Though it comes at the cost of some usability.

Group policy User User \ Administrative Templates \ Windows Components \ Windows Explorer

> Turns off the caching of thumbnails in hidden thumbs.db files.
>
> This policy setting allows you to configure Windows Explorer to cache
>   thumbnails of items residing in network folders in hidden thumbs.db
>   files.
>
> If you enable this policy setting, Windows Explorer does not create,
>   read from, or write to thumbs.db files. If you disable or do not
>   configure this policy setting, Windows Explorer creates, reads from,
>   and writes to thumbs.db files.

https://superuser.com/questions/2345/how-can-i-suppress-those-annoying-thumbs-db-files-in-windows-vista-and-windows-7